# Can't connect ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I have installed hadoop on ec2 ubuntu server, everything worked fine,but when i disconnected it and tried to open in another session using putty, it started giving me error at the time of connection.
The error is "server refused our key".
I have checked everything, like "key name", username, everything is correct.

can anybody suggest anything?

Thanks in advance.
AF

Comment: Is the instance running?

Comment: `server refused our key` means that the Private Key you are using to login does not match a key stored in the user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. So, check that you are using the correct username and the correct private key. One of them is _not_ correct.

Comment: yes, I checked, everything is fine, I checked the key in instance and username is also correct, I have installed hadoop on the server and when I closed the session, only after that I am not able to logged in.

Comment: Yes @cricket_007 instance is working